# Как рассчитать координаты x и y для конца пути в круге SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animation

У меня есть progress bar, который обновляется путем изменения свойства `stroke-dashoffset` path. Однако мне нужно вычислять координаты `x` и `y` конечной точки (округленной стороны) каждый раз, когда она обновляется.

Я собираюсь добавить метки в этих точках в будущем.  Я пытался использовать константы, похожие на
`const x = radius * Math.sin (Math.PI * 2 * angle / 360)`; и `const y = radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * angle / 360);`
но я не думаю, что использую их правильно. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне в этом деле?
Примечание: я использую только Vanilla JS

```js
const setStrokeDashOffset = (e) => {
  const dashOffset = e.target.getAttribute('data-attr');
  document
    .getElementById('progress-meter')
    .setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', dashOffset);
}


const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btn.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    setStrokeDashOffset(e)
  });
});
```

```css
.donut-progress__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.donut-progress__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.donut-progress__path-elapsed {
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.donut-progress__path-remaining {
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.donut-progress__path-start {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<svg id="donut-progress__svg" class="donut-progress__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g class="donut-progress__circle">
                <circle class="donut-progress__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                <path id="progress-meter" stroke-dasharray="283 283" stroke-dashoffset="165.08333333333334" class="donut-progress__path-remaining" stroke="#4764ae" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>
          <path opacity="1" id="progress-meter-start" class="donut-progress__path-start" stroke-dashoffset="282" stroke-dasharray="283" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>
            </g>
        </svg>


<button data-attr="100" class="one">move to 100</button>
<button data-attr="150" class="one">move to 150</button>
<button data-attr="200" class="one">move to 200</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Calculate the x and y for end of path within a circle SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60955892/7394871) от участника  [@Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021213/rafael).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60955892/7394871

Answer (score 2):

SVG предоставляет метод для элементов , который  будет для вас очень полезным:

`myPath.getPointAtLength(len)`

Пример кода ниже:

```js
const setStrokeDashOffset = (e) => {
  const dashOffset = e.target.getAttribute('data-attr');
  document
    .getElementById('progress-meter')
    .setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', dashOffset);
}


const showEndPoint = (e) => {
  const dashOffset = e.target.getAttribute('data-attr');
  // Получить X, Y координаты точки в «dashOffset» вдоль пути
  const pt = document
    .getElementById('progress-meter')
    .getPointAtLength(dashOffset);
  // Обновите нашу красную точку, чтобы показать местоположение
  // Обратите внимание, что мы переключаем X и Y здесь, чтобы компенсировать тот факт, что вы поворачиваете исходный путь
  const endpoint = document.getElementById('endpoint')
  endpoint.setAttribute('cx', pt.y);
  endpoint.setAttribute('cy', pt.x);
}


const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btn.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    setStrokeDashOffset(e);
    
    showEndPoint(e);
  });
});
```

```css
.donut-progress__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.donut-progress__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.donut-progress__path-elapsed {
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.donut-progress__path-remaining {
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.donut-progress__path-start {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<svg id="donut-progress__svg" class="donut-progress__svg" width="20%" height="20%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g class="donut-progress__circle">
                <circle class="donut-progress__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                <path id="progress-meter" stroke-dasharray="283 283" stroke-dashoffset="165.08333333333334" class="donut-progress__path-remaining" stroke="#4764ae" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>
          <path opacity="1" id="progress-meter-start" class="donut-progress__path-start" stroke-dashoffset="282" stroke-dasharray="283" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>
            </g>
      <circle id="endpoint" r="3" fill="red"/>
        </svg>


<button data-attr="100" class="one">move to 100</button>
<button data-attr="150" class="one">move to 150</button>
<button data-attr="200" class="one">move to 200</button>
```

А вот немного измененная версия SVG, в которой нет необходимости переключать координаты X и Y - как упоминалось в коде предыдущей версии.

```js
const setStrokeDashOffset = (e) => {
  const dashOffset = e.target.getAttribute('data-attr');
  document
    .getElementById('progress-meter')
    .setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', dashOffset);
}


const showEndPoint = (e) => {
  const dashOffset = e.target.getAttribute('data-attr');
  // Получить X, Y положение точки в «dashOffset» вдоль пути
  const path = document.getElementById('progress-meter');
  const pt = path.getPointAtLength(path.getTotalLength() - dashOffset);
  // Обновите нашу красную точку, чтобы показать местоположение
  const endpoint = document.getElementById('endpoint')
  endpoint.setAttribute('cx', pt.x);
  endpoint.setAttribute('cy', pt.y);
}


const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btn.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    setStrokeDashOffset(e);
    
    showEndPoint(e);
  });
});
```

```css
.donut-progress__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.donut-progress__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.donut-progress__path-elapsed {
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.donut-progress__path-remaining {
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.donut-progress__path-start {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="donut-progress__svg" class="donut-progress__svg" width="20%" height="20%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g class="donut-progress__circle">
                <circle class="donut-progress__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                <path id="progress-meter" stroke-dasharray="283 283" stroke-dashoffset="165.08333333333334" class="donut-progress__path-remaining" stroke="#4764ae" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>
          <path opacity="1" id="progress-meter-start" class="donut-progress__path-start" stroke-dashoffset="282" stroke-dasharray="283" d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -45, 0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
                    a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
                    "></path>

          <circle id="endpoint" r="3" fill="red"/>
            </g>
        </svg>


<button data-attr="100" class="one">move to 100</button>
<button data-attr="150" class="one">move to 150</button>
<button data-attr="200" class="one">move to 200</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Calculate the x and y for end of path within a circle SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957480/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>